# You can’t open the “Energy Saver” preferences pane because it is not available to you at this time.?

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-silicon

Today I see that in spotlight energy options, and this options is not working:
[image]
[image]

p.s

I have MacBook 16 from this year.

I want remove from mac this panel by sudo, but I can get information:

```
m@m /S/L/PreferencePanes> sudo rm -fr EnergySaver.prefPane/
rm: EnergySaver.prefPane//Contents/Resources/WOLShutOffList.plist: Operation not permitted
rm: EnergySaver.prefPane//Contents/Resources: Operation not permitted
rm: EnergySaver.prefPane//Contents: Operation not permitted
rm: EnergySaver.prefPane/: Operation not permitted
```

How I can fix it?